# Sending SIGINT through stdin

Tags: c, linux, bash

I'm currently writing an application that allows users to access the bash shell of a remote machine through telnet.  The application is a telnet server that runs on the remote machine.  I am piping the output from the telnet stream into a bash process that I spawned like so:

```
char *execArgs[] = {"/bin/bash", "-i", 0};
execv(execArgs[0], execArgs);
```

I am able to do almost everything you can do in a normal shell; typing commands, backspacing, etc.  However, I am having problems killing tasks with CTRL+C.  When I receive a CTRL+C sequence from the telnet end, it comes in as [0xFF][0xF8].  The FF puts the telnet into IAC mode (allowing it to interpret commands), and the F8 tells my program to send an ETX (0x03):

```
char tmpchar = 3;
retval = write(outfd[1], &tmpchar, 1);
fflush(fstdin);
```

Where outfd is the stream into the bash process.  However, I don't think the `0x03` is being interpreted as a SIGINT signal, or at least it isn't killing the currently running task.  Why would this be?

Comment: You should be sending it a `SIGINT`, not a `^C`! Are you using a pty to talk to `bash` or a pipe, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have no terminal, you cannot expect any terminal functions. So if you send a `^C` down the pipe, a `^C` will come out of the pipe. You can use `kill` to send a `SIGINT` to the process.

But you'd be much better off using a terminal to talk to `bash`! Shells expect to interact with terminals, not pipes. Punch `man pty` into your system to start learning how to do it right.

From the `pty(7)` man page:

> A  pseudoterminal  (sometimes abbreviated "pty") is a pair of virtual character devices that provide a bidirectional communication channel.  One end of the channel is called the master; the other end is called the  slave.
>          The  slave  end  of the pseudoterminal provides an interface that behaves exactly like a classical terminal.  A
>          process that expects to be connected to a terminal, can open the slave end of  a  pseudoterminal  and  then  be
>          driven  by a program that has opened the master end.
>
> Anything that is written on the master end is provided to
>          the process on the slave end as though it was input typed on a terminal.  For example,  writing  the  interrupt
>          character (usually control-C) to the master device would cause an interrupt signal (SIGINT) to be generated for
>          the foreground process group that is connected to the slave.  Conversely, anything that is written to the slave
>          end  of the pseudoterminal can be read by the process that is connected to the master end.  Pseudoterminals are
>          used by applications such as  network  login  services  (ssh(1),  rlogin(1),  telnet(1)),  terminal  emulators,
>          script(1), screen(1), and expect(1).

This is what you want.